# Using a case statement with SQL cursor to perform a calculation on each row and sum the results

Tags: sql-server

I am using a case statement and cursor together to perform a calculation on each row and then show the sum of the results.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  Name    Amount  Income_Frequency
123 Sam     500     Bi-weekly
123 Ralf    200     Weekly
123 Floyd   10000   Annual
```

I need to perform a calculation on each row as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Weekly' THEN Amount * 52
        WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Bi-weekly' THEN Amount * 26
        WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Monthly' THEN Amount * 12
        WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Annual' THEN Amount * 1
    ELSE '0'
    END
```

So, Sam's total income should be 13,000, Ralf's 10,400 and Floyd's 10,000. I then need to sum those 3 amounts to get 33,400.

Here's what I have tried that doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @Total decimal(9,2)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
(SELECT TOP(1)
        CASE
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Weekly' THEN Amount * 52
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Bi-weekly' THEN Amount * 26
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Monthly' THEN Amount * 12
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Annual' THEN Amount * 1
        ELSE '0'
        END  as AnnualIncome
        FROM MyTable where ID = 123)

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Total
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Total
    SELECT SUM(@Total)
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor, a straight query with a SUM around the case would work fine

Comment: @SteveFord I tried that but get a total of 10,000. Thanks.

Comment: just to add that there are very few cases when you will ever need to use a cursor. Try to avoid them as they are non-performant and more difficult to understand. SQL is a set based language and should be used in this way rather than using iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c68ea/5)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  ID      INT,
  Name    VARCHAR(20),
  Amount  Decimal(9,2),
  Income_Frequency VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES
  (123,  'Sam',500, 'Bi-weekly'),
  (123,  'Ralf',200, 'Weekly'),
  (123,  'Floyd',10000, 'Annual')
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Total decimal(9,2)

SELECT @Total= SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Weekly' THEN Amount * 52
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Bi-weekly' THEN Amount * 26
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Monthly' THEN Amount * 12
            WHEN Income_Frequency = 'Annual' THEN Amount * 1
            ELSE 0
        END)  
FROM MyTable
where ID = 123

SELECT @Total
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c68ea/5/0)**:

```
|       |
|-------|
| 33400 |
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on Steve's comment.

Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=43067e3145e136b489b2e0c05b3730eb)

```
Select Annual = sum( Amount *
                     CASE Income_Frequency 
                     WHEN 'Weekly'    THEN 52
                     WHEN 'Bi-weekly' THEN 26
                     WHEN 'Monthly'   THEN 12
                     WHEN 'Annual'    THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                     END 
                 )
 From YourTable
 Where ID = 123
```

**Results**

```
Annual
33400
```

Comment: Note that the `CASE` can be written slightly more elegantly (IMO) as `CASE Income_Frequency WHEN 'Weekly' THEN 52 ...` The `ELSE` can be left out entirely without affecting the result (but if it remains it ought to be `0` and not `'0'`).

Comment: Just to expand on the expand on Steve's comment.   Since the Math is directly related to the values of the current row (simple math) - SQL Server will be able to do a "Set Based Operation"  It will be massively faster and more efficient than a cursor.   If you are doing a SUM or AVG in a cursor loop you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @SqlSurfer  You're right.  More words... More better  :)